# Contiperf2 not working with my existing JUnit test case

Tags: java, performance-testing, junit4, contiperf

For performance testing, I am trying to use Contiperf http://databene.org/contiperf with my JUnit testcases

With independent test class contiperf is working.

but when I using Contiperf with my existing passing test case, its not working.

```
    import org.databene.contiperf.junit.ContiPerfRule;
    import org.databene.contiperf.junit.ContiPerfSuiteRunner;
    import org.junit.Rule;        

    public class TU_XSL_OrderDlt extends TranslatorUtls  {

                @Rule
                public ContiPerfRule i = new ContiPerfRule();
                @Test    
                @PerfTest(invocations = 1, threads = 1) 
                public void testNormalTranslation() throws Exception {

               assertTranslation("testdata/OrderDeltInput.xml", "testdata/OrderDltOutput.xml");
            }

        }
```

Following exception I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: fNext
    at org.databene.contiperf.junit.ContiPerfRule.apply(ContiPerfRule.java:176)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.withMethodRules(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:365)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.withRules(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:355)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:278)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: fNext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)
    at org.databene.contiperf.junit.ContiPerfRule.apply(ContiPerfRule.java:166)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: What version of junit and contiperf are you using? I have the same issue with my test case. It works fine with junit 4.10 while not with 4.12. I assume any version of junit between 4.7 and 4.10 is what is being supported. Once when I downgraded junit version to 4.10 it worked. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

JUnit 4.12 applies that field renaming, the PR to fix it [was sent a long time ago](https://github.com/lucaspouzac/contiperf/pull/10).

I suggest you use [version 2.4.3](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.javatlacati/contiperf/2.4.3/jar) that has the change and is already on maven central.

Please note that the dependency group has changed, but other than changing the imports the code should remain the same.